# Gearmand not starting properly, getting "multiple occurences" returned

Tags: syslog, gearman

Gearmand ran for about a day before I tried to restart it and it wouldn't come back up. Getting the following and the syslog doesn't have anything in it that refers to gearman.

```
~$ /etc/init.d/gearman-job-server stop && /etc/init.d/gearman-job-server start
 * Stopping Gearman Server gearmand                                                                                                                                                                         No /usr/sbin/gearmand found running; none killed.
                                                                                                                                                                                                     [ OK ]
 * Starting Gearman Server gearmand                                                                                                                                                                         multiple occurrences
                                                                                                                                                                                                     [fail]
 * Please take a look at the syslog
```

Answer (score 1):

Just had this problem too. I think the 'multiple occurrences' is referring to a conflicting commandline switch

In my case I was passing --listen=127.0.0.1 aswell as --listen=0.0.0.0 
Removing 127.0.0.1 fixed the problem

Comment: not only 127.0.0.1 vs 0.0.0.0... any double parameter will cause this. for example: -d -d.